# Accept user input for criteria in Sqlite query

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, pandasql

Is it possible to accept user input for the date in the BETWEEN {} and AND {} criteria?

For example, instead of having to hardcode two dates, I want to be prompted to insert two dates in a textbox --or something.

```
a = """
SELECT SUM(
CASE WHEN dates.dates BETWEEN '2020-06-20' AND '2020-06-24' <----
AND employee_area = 'afd.56'
AND employee_shift = 'day'
AND wkday_num IN ('1','2','3','4')
THEN employees.day ELSE 0 END) AS b
FROM dates, employees
"""
```

Comment: Please show fuller code block. We need to see your DB-API. You only show an SQL string not how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

try pass a `?` as a parameter, which you can do multiple times:

```
a = """
SELECT SUM(
CASE WHEN dates.dates BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND employee_area = 'afd.56'
AND employee_shift = 'day'
AND wkday_num IN ('1','2','3','4')
THEN employees.day ELSE 0 END) AS b
FROM dates, employees
"""
vars = (date1,date2)
cursor = cnxn.execute(a, vars)
```

Comment: Between ? AND ? returns a syntax error message, unfortunately

Comment: Please show your fuller implementation and exact error message.